# CodeMirror highlighting on find

Tags: codemirror

I want to recreate the find function in CodeMirror for highlight each occurrence like showed in [this demo](https://codemirror.net/demo/search.html).

I have created an example using `marks`, but highlight only the first occurrence.
http://jsfiddle.net/oxmgm4sd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `if (cursor.findNext())` to `while (cursor.findNext())` might already get you somewhere. It is more efficient (though also a little more complicated) to use an [overlay](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addOverlay) instead, which is what the built-in search functionality does.